# Why can't I refer the id using delegate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I supply some html data with the `append()` function in Javascript like:

```
$("#box").append("<button class='primary' id='1'>Button 1</button><button class='primary' id='2'>Button 2</button>");
```

And, on using `delegate()` or `on()` the referred id is being undefined:

```
$("div#box button.primary").on("click",function(){
        var btnId = $(this).id;

        //Do something Using the Button Id
        alert("Ouch! You clicked button " + btnId);

});
```

It alerts

> Ouch! You clicked button undefined

Why can't I refer the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
var btnId = this.id;
```

The `id` belongs to the dom element, `this` refers to the dom element, but when you say `$(this).id` it tries to fetch the `id` property of a jQuery object which is not defined.

You could either fetch the `id` using the dom element reference like `this.id` or use jQuery's `.attr()` like `$(this).attr('id')`